# D3DCSX 11 Problems hooking up and running FFT function

Tags: directx-11, directcompute

as per title I have problems setting up and running DirectX11 GPU-based FFTs using D3DCSX 11
(System: Win10 Pro + MS Visual Studio community 2022 (ver: 17.8.3),  Windows kit 10 (ver: 10.0.22621.0) )

My includes and linked files:

```
#include <d3dcsx.h> 

#pragma comment(lib, "d3dcsx.lib")
```

This should suffice as per MS reference guide.  However, if I start my application and call `D3DX11CreateFFT(..)` for example, I get an error window stating `d3dcsx.dll` cannot be found. I worked around by copying `d3dcsx_47.dll` from the kit 10 `bin` directory into my executable directory and renaming it to `d3dcsx.dll`.  While the error message vanished, now I get an E_OUTOFMEMORY error on calling functions like `D3DX11CreateFFT(..)` no matter what parameters I provide.

I guess something is wrong with the windows kit 10 installation but its all new installed on a new system.  It seems the internal reference from `d3dcsx.lib` to the actual `d3dcsx_47.dll` is broken, but I have no idea how to fix this. Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: Deploying d3dcsx_47.dll yourself is expected behavior, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250832/is-it-necessary-to-redistribute-directx-from-the-windows-sdk as for the D3DX11CreateFFT you should provide some reproducing code [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you Simon for your quick answer. What still puzzles me is these first few lines in the d3dcsx.h file that point to the right file name: 

`// Current name of the DLL shipped in the same SDK as this header. 

#define D3DCSX_DLL_W L"d3dcsx_47.dll" 
#define D3DCSX_DLL_A "d3dcsx_47.dll" 
#ifdef UNICODE 
#define D3DCSX_DLL D3DCSX_DLL_W 
#else 
#define D3DCSX_DLL D3DCSX_DLL_A #endif`  

Why do I still have to manually rename d3dcsx_47.dll ?  Thanks again.

Comment: You have to rename because d3dcsx.lib references d3dcsx.dll, not a versioned file name. Not sure what these defines are for, maybe if you want to link dynamically to the dll (LoadLibrary+GetProcAddress), but since you're supposed to ship it yourself it seems quite useless. Or maybe for tooling support (like if you want to programmatically build a deployment tool...). It's always been defined like that 15 years at least.

Comment: Thanks again, so I just take the renaming part as a requirement.
I was able to get rid of the `E_OUTOFMEMORY` error in the meantime, so everything seems fine for now. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You should answer yourself with some details then.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem seems not fixed yet: creating a device and context using `D3D11CreateDevice(..)`,  the function `D3DX11CreateFFT(..)` runs just fine.  However, it will fail with E_OUTOFMEMORY error with contexts created with `DXUTCreateDevice(..)` .  I spend a lot of time comparing the contexts using `CheckFeatureSupport()` etc. but I see no reason why the device context generated with DXUT fails while my own one succeeds.

Comment: Which DXUT are you using? The legacy one with D3D9/D3D11 support or the latest from [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/DXUT/)?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I downloaded the latest from Github you referenced above, same result.  Here is my minimal code producing that error:

`#include<Windows.h>
#include<atlbase.h>
#include<d3d11.h>
#include<D3dcsx.h>
#include<DXUT.h>

int main()
{
 HRESULT hr;
 hr = DXUTCreateDevice(D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0, true, 640, 480);
 auto pDXUTContext = DXUTGetD3D11DeviceContext();
 D3DX11_FFT_BUFFER_INFO  fftbufferinfo = {};
 CComPtr<ID3DX11FFT> pFFT = 0;
 hr = D3DX11CreateFFT2DReal(pDXUTContext, 16, 16, 0, &fftbufferinfo, &pFFT);
}
`
Big thanks again for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using DXUT at all here. You aren't doing all the things as shown in *EmptyProject* needed to use DXUT in the first place. I'll try it out.

Comment: Also, why use legacy ATL instead of WRL ComPtr?

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChuckWalbourn, I tried to extend an old framework with DX FFT support, that is based on DXUT.  When I realized FFT does not work with DXUT device contexts, I created this minimum example using the newest DXUT version to illustrate the problem.  I assumed just calling `DXUTCreateDevice` will be enough since I got back a proper device + context.  I will try to implement the steps from the _EmptyProject_ although to be honest I don't think this will give me a different result (i.e. a working FFT using an DXUT context).   Big thanks again!

Comment: I implemented the functions in _EmptyProject_ (I used this one [EmptyProject11](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/blob/main/EmptyProject11/EmptyProject11.cpp) ) but no luck: the DXUT device context still does not work with the FFT function, giving `E_OUTOFMEMORY`.

Comment: In an attempt to go with a modern Windows DirectX interface I tried to get the FFT running in 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/tutorial--create-your-first-uwp-directx-game'  (A simple UWP game example).  Unfortunately, this seems not compatible with `d3dcsx.h`,  due to the this line `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)`.  @ChuckWalbourn any advice what sample/project to start with to get DX11 FFT running?  Again, many thanks in advance.

Comment: UWP doesn't support D3DCSX because that DLL is not built into the OS and won't pass the "WACK" tool validation of imports. Note that some 'modern' basic device & swapchain loops can be found [here](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates). Unfortunately l never did much with D3DCSX and I don't see any samples for it. You would probably find better support for it on the [DirectX Discord](https://discord.com/invite/directx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer here is that implicit linking with D3DXCS.LIB / D3DCSX_47.DLL is broken. The import library doesn't reference the correct DLL name. While renaming the DLL for your local deployment works, it means that it can't find the PDB files on the Microsoft Symbol Server.

Therefore, you should *really* use explicit linking if you are going to make use of D3DXCS11.

```
    auto hmod = LoadLibraryW(D3DCSX_DLL_W);
    if (!hmod)
        return 1;

    using PFN_D3DX11CreateFFT2DReal = HRESULT (WINAPI *)(
        ID3D11DeviceContext * pDeviceContext,
        UINT X,
        UINT Y,
        UINT Flags,
        _Out_ D3DX11_FFT_BUFFER_INFO * pBufferInfo,
        _Out_ ID3DX11FFT * *ppFFT
    );

    auto createFFT2DReal = reinterpret_cast<PFN_D3DX11CreateFFT2DReal>(static_cast<void*>(GetProcAddress(hmod, "D3DX11CreateFFT2DReal")));
    if (!createFFT2DReal)
        return 1;
    
    D3DX11_FFT_BUFFER_INFO  fftbufferinfo = {};
    CComPtr<ID3DX11FFT> pFFT = 0;
    HRESULT hr = createFFT2DReal(pContext, 16, 16, 0, &fftbufferinfo, &pFFT);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return 1;
```

And you need to copy the DLL file to your local build directory:

```
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\D3D\x64\d3dcsx_47.dll" $(OutDir)
```

The other problem is that the D3DXCS11 library will return `E_OUTOFMEMORY` for all kinds of errors, so it's not particular informative.

Comment: Yes the above solves the first part of the problem (broken linking to the right DLL), thanks a lot @ChuckWalborn!   
The second part (DXUT device context not working with DX11 FFT) is still under investigation.